# Fedora 24 switch from KDE spin to Default (GNOME)

Tags: fedora, package-management, kde, desktop-environment, dnf

I have installed the default workstation group

```
dnf install @workstation-product-environment
```

Now I want to remove all unnecessary KDE packages but

```
dnf remove @kde-desktop-environtment
```

gives me this error.

```
Dependencies resolved.
Error: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf, systemd.
```

and `dnf remove @kde` wants to remove packages that I just installed that are not related to KDE (such as tkinter, redhat-menus, gnome-shell, and gnome-session)

how can I remove KDE without breaking my system?